# Pakistani tourist visa requirements for Venice

Tags: tourist-visas, pakistani-citizens

I am planning to visit Venice, northeastern Italy for vacation (1 month) with my family (3 adult members). Is there any specific visa requirements for me and my family traveling from Pakistan to Italy?

Comment: The requirement is that you each need a visa (assuming that you are all citizens of Pakistan).  Is that the answer you are looking for, or is there some additional specificity you seek?

Comment: @Rahat Batool Have you checked this site http://www.italyvisa-pakistan.com/

Comment: Further to phoog's answer, you may also need transit visas for any country/countries you will pass through on your way to Italy.

Comment: @Traveller Thanks alot as you give me reference of very good site and I found all my solutions.

Comment: @Giorgio Answer added

Comment: There are no specific visa requirements for Venice. Just follow the same rules as you would for anywhere else in Italy.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are all Pakistani citizens, you each need a visa. You can apply here http://www.italyvisa-pakistan.com/